# LUA ERROR I Can't Figure Out

Tags: error-handling, lua

[This is the error](http://pastebin.com/7XXtQ0F9)

```
[ERROR] gamemodes/taloslife/gamemode/cl_networking.lua:99: attempt to index a nil value
```

[This is the file:](http://pastebin.com/NVMFLDmn)

Can't add it because of maximum word length, but here's the code block in which 99 is in

```
function GM.Net:GetProtocolIDByName( strProtocol )
    return self.m_tblProtocols.Names[strProtocol].ID
end
```

I really can not figure out what's wrong with this, If anyone could please tell me the fix it would be greatly appreciated.  I have spent hours looking into this and can't find the fix.

Comment: Paste the error. Paste the file.

Comment: Click on "This is the error"

Comment: Click on This is the File

Comment: File on pastebin say line 99 is in next function, not the one you've quoted.

Answer (score 1):

When you read something that is not there in Names table, you will get nil.

> return self.m_tblProtocols.**Names[strProtocol]**.ID

And then you're trying to get ID field from nil value, so you get this "attempt to index nil" error.

Check if protocol name is saved in that table first.

Comment: 'GM.Net.m_tblProtocols.Names' table is either empty, or doesn't store value for some protocol name. Add checks around that line, see if 'self.m_tblProtocols.Names[strProtocol]' evaluates to value of type "table", only then you can read field ID from that value.